# Jenkins Pipeline: Run the step when you see a new file or when it changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a laravel application that requires the "yarn" command at initialization, and later only if certain files are changed.

Using the code below, I manage to detect when that file has changed, but I need a suggestion to be able to run it at the first initialization (practically, that file together with all the others seem to be new files from the perspective of the Jenkinsfile).

Thanks!

Current try:

```
        stage("Install NodeJS dependencies") {

            when {

                changeset "package.json"

            }

            agent {

                docker {

                    image 'node:14-alpine'
                    reuseNode true

                }

            }

            steps {
                sh 'yarn --silent'
                sh 'yarn dev --silent'
                
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about your question? What do you mean by first initialization? If "practically, that file together with all the others seem to be new files from the perspective of the Jenkinsfile", shouldn't the when condition be true?

Comment: By initialization I mean that I add, for example, the current repository in Jenkins and build it. How can I make the yarn commands run even though the package.json file is practically a new file for jenkins, not a changed file.